# Fetching near to half million records from an REST api

Tags: c#, .net, rest

We have been provided with an REST api for product information.
Our goal is to fetch the product information by calling the api and load them into our databases.
The api can only result 400 records per call and we need to fetch near to quarter/half million records with an ETA of 8 hours to complete.
What are some best approaches to build a solution for this?

Comment: hi, do you mean showing half million records on one call?

Comment: Nope. Ultimately i need to fetch half million records but the api only returns 400 records per call . I would be making multiple calls to fetch the records(400 at a time) and insert the records into my database. What i am looking for is best approach to do this , what are some suggestible patterns to implement this.

Comment: have you tried putting start and limit on your api call? First call will get the first set of record then second call will show the next set and so on...  You can show your existing code.

Comment: 500000 records / 400 records per call = 1250 calls. 8 hours x 3600 seconds/hr = 28800 seconds. You need to get record(s) in 28800 secs/ 1250 call = 23.04 secs per call

Comment: @bogzy i haven't yet started my build , we are still researching on the best approaches to fetch the data . We are also trying to think of the Pub-Sub model for which we need to convince the api provider . Going with the api call , we might have service timeouts and offline , which would be tough to handle the records we failed to load for that instance